# Cannot open VS 2010 solution file in Xamarin Studio (MonoDevelop)

Tags: c#, xamarin-studio

I have built an  `ASP.NET Web Service` in `C#` and  and I need to run this on `Linux`. After googling, I found out that it's possible to execute `ASP.NET` web service on `Linux` using Mono Develop. But when I try to open my Solution File in Mono (Xamarin Studio) it gives me an error:

**Error while trying to load the project.**

What am I doing wrong? Or maybe what is the best solution to run `ASP.NET Web Service` on `Linux`?

**EDIT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
<compilation defaultLanguage="C#" debug="true">
  <assemblies>
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly">
</customErrors>
<authentication mode="None">
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
<httpHandlers>
</httpHandlers>
<trace enabled="false" localOnly="true" pageOutput="false" requestLimit="10" traceMode="SortByTime" />
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20" />
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
<pages>
</pages>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it can fail for a lot of reasons, so add a bug report into [Xamarin's Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/). But try initially to start Xamarin Studio, choose create new Asp.Net solution and then replace with your files in the .vcproj file (you can use a simple xml editor like gedit or Notepad++).

Depends on your application kind, I found that simple web pages/web services work but is not using IIS, but is using XSP4 (their custom C# written IIS-like web server) which sometimes is slow.

If you need simply to make some business logic to run fast on Mono and to not have configuration hassles, I would recommend to you [.Net remoting](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14791/NET-Remoting-with-an-easy-example). This is a low-overhead solution and I found it working even in combination with binary serialization.

Comment: I created a new ASP.NET Web App solution in Xamarin and replaced codes with the codes from my ASP.NET Web Service. It's giving me `HTTP 500.19 - Internal Server Error` when running. What do i need to change in my `web.config`?

Comment: You have web.config file in your project. I have it by default.

So you can do it using XamarinStudio.

Comment: I have posted my Xamarian Studio `web.config`. Can you please take a look, what is wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I just tried the default sample and it runs on my machine (albeit is running on Windows) with no change and it run well. Try to reduce your sample and add gradually code until it breaks.